# Get infobox in map to show up when clicking link outside of the map

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps, maps

I was wondering if someone knows how I could make the 'links', beneath the map, interact with the map (see image below).

Let's say I want to click on George.. Than the infobox in the map should be visible. If I click on another, then that one should be visible, etc..

The HTML with the links:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>George</a></li>
   <li><a>Hoppe</a></li>
   <li><a>Café Herengracht</a></li>
</ul>
```

The HTML from the infobox:

```
<div>
   <div class="infoBox"></div>
// here comes another infobox (when clicked on icon)
// here comes another infobox (when clicked on icon)
// here comes another infobox (when clicked on icon)
// etc..
</div>
```

The other infoboxes are not in the DOM now.. only when you click on them in the map!

I don't know where to find the javascript and If I knew I don't think I would recognize the function that makes the infobox appear in the DOM.

[image: This is a screenshot from a section of my site]

I'm using this map shortcode in the Avade Wordpress Theme:
https://avada.theme-fusion.com/google-maps/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to allow multiple info windows open at once? If not, I would recommend only having a single info window element. With a single info window all you would need to do is listen for click event(s) then once clicked set the position and content of the info window then open.

The [Google Maps JavaScript API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents) has an example of [Listening to DOM events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener) which shows how to interact with the map with elements outside the map (in your case links below the map).

The pseudo code below shows a very basic overview on how to register a 'click' event listener which updates and shows the info window. For more on the [Google Maps Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) check out the [example on info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><a id="mapTriggerGeorge">George</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello World!'
});

var georgeTrigger = document.getElementById('mapTriggerGeorge');

google.maps.event.addDomListener(georgeTrigger, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent('Hello World from George!');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```